# MUI: Keep track of multiple Checkbox states

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a checkbox element within a tab using MUI. When switching tabs it removes the checkbox visual.

```
{listItem.map((checkbox, index) => {
          return (
            <FormControlLabel className="twocolelement"
        control={
          <Checkbox
          key={(index) + (checkbox.Name)}
            name={checkbox.Name}
            value={checkbox.Weight}
            id={checkbox.Category}
            checked={isChecked==index}
            color="primary"
            onChange={event => handleCheckboxChange(index, event)}
            onClick={() => isCheckboxChecked(index)}
          />
        }
        label={(checkbox.Brand) + ' ' + (checkbox.Name)}
      />

          );
        })}
```

```
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState([]);

  const isCheckboxChecked = (index) => {
    setIsChecked(index)
    console.log(index)
}
```

This keeps the state but it works like a radio button (only allowing one selection)

How do I keep the checkbox state (checked) when moving between tabs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store all of the `Checkbox`s state:

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState(() =>
  listItem.map((i) => false)
);

const isCheckboxChecked = (index, checked) => {
  setIsChecked((isChecked) => {
    return isChecked.map((c, i) => {
      if (i === index) return checked;
      return c;
    });
  });
};
console.log(isChecked);

return (
  <div>
    {listItem.map((checkbox, index) => {
      return (
        <FormControlLabel
          key={index + checkbox.name}
          className="twocolelement"
          control={
            <Checkbox
              name={checkbox.name}
              value={checkbox.weight}
              id={checkbox.category}
              checked={isChecked[index]}
              color="primary"
              onChange={(e) => isCheckboxChecked(index, e.target.checked)}
            />
          }
          label={checkbox.name}
        />
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thank you - the array on isChecked returns empty for me ... any suggestions why so?

Comment: @PaulVI `isChecked` is never empty in my code because I initialize it with a default array value, can you fork my codesandbox and reproduce the error so I can see what's wrong?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the reading of listItem. I read this in from firebase so const listItem = useItems(); and then useItems() is the firebase onsnapshot read.

Comment: This is different from the code in your question, so I can't guess what's wrong unless you make a reproducible codesandbox. @PaulVI

Comment: that might be a little difficult to do - the checkboxes are within a Material UI tab - and they disappear. Also try as I might isChecked is always empty...